# header location not working fine with godaddy linux hosting

Tags: php, html

i have hosted my site on godaddy, but header(location: ) is not working fine. I mean it doesn't execute at all. Whereas it was running properly in other hosting sites and localhost.Please help me ?

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
header("Location:index.html");
exit;
}

else if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$first_name = $_POST['firstname'];
$last_name = $_POST['lastname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$category = $_POST['category'];
$enquiry = $_POST['enquiry'];

$to = 'contact.vstudy@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Enquiry';
$msg = "First name: $first_name\n <br />" .
"Last name: $last_name\n<br />" .
"Email: $email\n<br />" .
"Category: $category\n<br />" .
"Enquiry: $enquiry.\n<br />";
mail($to, $subject, $msg, 'From:' . $email);
?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP header() redirection is not working in Godaddy host](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25451097/php-header-redirection-is-not-working-in-godaddy-host)

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer is that you don't have protocol in the URL:

```
header("Location:www.vstudy.in");
```

Should have been

```
header("Location: http://www.vstudy.in");
```

Comment: I refuse to believe that this actually worked on any sites... if you did a `header("Location:www.vstudy.in");` it should redirect to a local file named www.vstudy.in, not the domain...

Comment: And if it doesn't work at all, then I guess that it is because output is already started, as the link by Douwe de Haan suggests.

Comment: srry it was actually index.html not www.vstudy.in.. i have editted by post

Comment: and the above is working on other side ... i am giving you the link for both     www.vstudy.in - click on it and type www.vstudy.in/vstudy.php ... it will show nothing and then open lucky06111.esy.es/index.html  and here type lucky06111.esy.es/vStudy.php---- it will redirect again to  lucky06111.esy.es/index.html... which is not happening in 1st case whereas code is same for both